# Save an array of objects in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-submit

Hi I'm trying to put together the next object

$scope.passengers = {
         adult : [ {firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"},{firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"},{firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"}],
         child : [ {firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"},{firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"},{firstname: "name", lastname: "anothername"}],
    extras : "someValue"} ;

In my controller I have the following

```
$scope.passengers = {};
$scope.passengers.adult = [];
$scope.passengers.child = [];
$scope.numberAdult = 10;
$scope.numberChildren = 10;
Y las funciones
//Functions return an array null
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    num = parseInt(num);
    return new Array(num);   
};
$scope.savePassengers = function(product_id)
 {
    //for the moment only print the variable
    console.log($scope.passengers)
 }
```

In My HTML page

```
<form name="passengers-form" ng-submit="savePassengers(product.id)">        
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group"  ng-repeat="a in getNumber(numberAdult) track by $index">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Adult {{$index + 1 }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input  required  ng-model="passengers.adult[$index].firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input  required ng-model="passengers.adult[$index].lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"  ng-repeat="a in getNumber(numberChildren) track by $index">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Child {{$index + 1 }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input  required ng-model="passengers.child[$index].firstname"  class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input  required  ng-model="passengers.child[$index].lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Extras</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <textarea name="" ng-model="passengers.extras"class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">

                    <div class="form-group buttons pull-right">                                                                 

                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Add to Cart ->
                        </button>                                                                                                                                       
                    </div>
                </div>                  

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>      
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

But, when i print the variable "passenger" , the console show : `Object {extras: "someValue"}`

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates this. It's not obvious where problem might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `ng-repeat` creates an isolated scope, so your input fields are not reflecting in the correct scope. This can further be verified by your `extras` field being properly fulfilled.

You should change these lines in your HTML:

```
<input  required  ng-model="$parent.passengers.adult[$index].firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
...
<input  required ng-model="$parent.passengers.adult[$index].lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
```

And do the same thing for the children area.